# custom error pages for non existent controllers in apiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I have created a MVC web API with MVC 5 controller for managing CRUD operations.

Here is the snippet of my API controller:

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
    {// GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            UserRepository urepo = new UserRepository();
            return urepo.UserList(0);
        }

        public User GetUserByID(int userID)
        {
            UserRepository urepo = new UserRepository();
            var userDetails = urepo.UserList(userID);  

            return (from n in userDetails where n.UserId == userID select n).SingleOrDefault();
        } }
```

and here is my WebAPIconfig file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When I access this controller from URL say **localhost/api/User/GetAllUsers**
it is returning all users as expected.

But if i try to access in other way say **localhost/api/User** which is not there , will throw file not found error and show default error page.

what i need is instead of this default error page custom error page need to be displayed.
How this can be achieved?

Comment: Is it the custom error page on **API url**  that you wanted to display?

Comment: @HEGDE yes ,That is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you are developing a HTTP RESTful application using ASP.NET Web API framework. In this application you need to handle HTTP 404 errors in a centralized location.
This Blog might help you in finding what you need.

[Handling HTTP 404 Error in ASP.NET Web API](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Thank you.
It helped in solving although i used a different method to achieve it.